# Add colors that depend on chapters to the TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, color, tocloft

I'would like to add different colors in my TOC, depending on the chapter. I've a color for the header, section subsection of each chapter (red chapter  one, blue chapter two etc...). With this code I can change colors of chapter name, section and subsection, but this style is the same of all the TOC:

```
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\makeatletter

\let\stdl@section\l@section

\renewcommand*{\l@subsection}[2]{%
  \stdl@subsection{\it\bf\textcolor{DarkGreen}{#1}}{\it\bf\textcolor{DarkGreen}{#2}}}
\makeatother
```

I'm a newbie, I would to exprime like an `"if chapter==1 \textcolor{DarkGreen}" "if chapter==2 \textcolor{Red}"`... Any ideas?

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Just a hint: when entering code in your question, you can indent it with four spaces to get a nice formatting. =)

Comment: Which document class are you using? In your question you talk about changing the color for the chapter entries in the ToC, but your code refers to sections and subsections. Which sectional units must be affected?

Answer (score 13):

You can try the following:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\newcounter{chapcntr}
\setcounter{chapcntr}{-1}
\newcommand*\toccolor{%
    \ifcase\value{chapcntr}%
         \color{red}%----- 0 --
    \or  \color{blue}%---- 1 --
    \or  \color{green}%--- 2 --
    \or  \color{cyan}%---- 3 --
    \else \color{black}%-- default
    \fi}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand*\cftchapfont{\stepcounter{chapcntr}\toccolor\bfseries}
\renewcommand*\cftchappagefont{\toccolor\bfseries}

\renewcommand*\cftsecfont{\toccolor}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\toccolor\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
\renewcommand*\cftsecpagefont{\toccolor}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
  \chapter{First chapter}
  \section{A section}
  \section{Another section}
  \chapter{Second chapter}
  \section{A section}
  \section{Another section}
\appendix
  \chapter{First appendix}
  \section{A section}
  \section{Another section}
\backmatter
\end{document}
```

Resulting in

[image]

Comment: Thankyou very much for the answer! Is that any way to color just the number of the sub section (2.1,2.2)? 
I cannot find it in the tocloft documentation. Thankyou again!

Comment: I found the answer... To color just the numbers of section and Note subsection: 
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecpresnum}{\toccolor}
withot
\renewcommand*\cftsubsecfont{\toccolor}

Comment: Thanks to your answer I've learned how to use `\ifcase` :).