# How to highlight specific entries in a tocloft-formatted ToC

Tags: tikz-pgf, table-of-contents, highlighting, tocloft

I am writing a document using the `book` class, and I use `tocloft` in order to customize the appearance of my ToC. So far, the package did a great job for most customizations, except for one thing: I am trying to highlight ToC entries for the book parts (created with `\part`) with a grey box. Is there any way to do that?

I found `\colorbox` and `soul` as solutions for highlighting text in general, but I do not have an idea how to apply them to the ToC entries for parts.

Comment: Have you looked at [Add colors that depend on chapters to the TOC](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18635/1952) or [How to customize the table of contents using TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19796/1952) ?

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions! I already knew the first one, but it does not really help me as I am trying to highlight the background of a text, not the text itself. However, the second solution looks promising. Maybe I end up switching to `titletoc`. Just wondered whether there was a way doing it with `tocloft`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a solution using `tikz` and `tocloft`.  It places hidden nodes in the `tocloft` formatting commands for `part` and then uses the `overlay` function of `tikz` to draw the box.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
% command to make a hidden node
\newcommand*{\hnode}[1]{%
    \tikz[remember picture] \node[minimum size=0pt,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=5pt] (#1) {};}
% create a node at the beginning of the part entry
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\hnode{P1}\bfseries\Large}
\renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\bfseries}
% create a node at the end of the part page number and draw the gray box
\renewcommand{\cftpartafterpnum}{%
  \hnode{P2}\tikz[remember picture,overlay] 
  \draw (P1.north west)  [line width={25pt}, gray,opacity=.2] -- (P2.north east);}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{First part}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\part{Second Part}
\chapter{Another chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Note that you need to compile your document twice to have the overlay align correctly.

Comment: This one works like a charm! Thank you very much!