# How to add some visual style and pizzazz to course notes?

Tags: packages, formatting, typography

LaTeX is wonderful for writing mathematical papers, but while the output is perfectly typeset it is not visually very exciting. And although it may just be "familiarity breeds contempt", I am basically fed up of the CMR fonts.

I want to write some course notes that don't look like a dry mathematical paper, but rather have a bit of additional "pizzazz" to relieve the visual monotony for the students, and to provide subtle visual assistance in navigating the notes.

It's not that I want the course notes to look like a 1000-page Calculus text or a ".. For Dummies" book where the entire book is a mass of cute little icons, call-outs, footnotes, marginal comments, cartoons etc, but just something that gives some attractive chapter and section headings, a few distinct ways to frame material that is either background, or advanced or otherwise to be separated from the main flow.

I've searched a bit and the most promising thing to explore further that I have come across so far is a package called "memoir".

Does anyone else have any recommendations?

Comment: What subject do the course notes cover?

Comment: First year Linear Algebra

Comment: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/comicsans (ok, just kidding)

Comment: Perhaps [Showcase of beautiful typography done in TeX & friends](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends) is what you are looking for?

Comment: Would the tag {[tag:fun]} take away from this question's authority too much?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I think it depends a lot on the subject of your lecture notes. Good lecture notes should be readable, easy to file and easily identifiable as *your* notes, i.e., your own distinct style. Personally I don't like the idea of framing things up too much. I would recommend
you use the [grid](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/grid) package.

[image]

Another alternative, is the [tufte-latex](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex) class. This is a good class, especially if you want to talk to the students via "sidenotes" and ancillary material can go in the margins.

Whatever, you decide on spend some time to develop the first couple of lecture notes. They are the beginning of the start of your future book!

Comment: The documentation to the `grid` package is greatly inspirational in terms of design. Thank you for bringing my attention to it.

Comment: Those tables with broken vertical lines are ugly!

Comment: @Aditya One has to style them to what he likes:)

Answer (score 41):

I would second Yiannis recommendation of the `tufte-latex` (`T-L`) class and provide an example out of a PhD thesis in physics (sorry, German. `T-L` supports handouts and books. It also uses Palatino as the default font. If you dislike the LateX default fonts in particular, because you see them everywhere, you could try to use Xe- or Lua-LaTeX and load any system font you like.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. It is a great example of usage of the class, especially given the poor design of most the theses classes. I also like the graphic, which is almost like sparklines! One thing for the class is that it looks better with a lot of text. I tried it with code and did not work very well. Did you do the graphic with TikZ?

Comment: We also used some sparklines with the `sparkline` package, but not on that page. We do our figures with `Igor` and then use `Illustrator`. It seems like a weird idea, I got it from Edward Tufte's blog. It works really well.

Comment: Great example of typesetting. I always love to see good layouts done with LaTeX.

Answer (score 21):

There have been some amazing demonstrations here on TeX.sx of using the `TikZ` package to provide colourful enhancements to page headings, section headings, and such.

Here are some links that have beautiful results (not all of them use `TikZ`):

- [How to get a colored box as the header?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33305/how-to-get-a-colored-box-as-the-header)
- [How to place a shaded box around a section label and name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34288/how-to-place-a-shaded-box-around-a-section-label-and-name)
- [Add colors that depend on chapters to the TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18635/add-colors-that-depend-on-chapters-to-the-toc)
- [Adding a per-chapter image along with group of entries in ToC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31518/adding-a-per-chapter-image-along-with-group-of-entries-in-toc)

Answer (score 7):

I sometimes use randomized frames to remove the visual monotonicity of course notes. One example is [this](http://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/mahajan/assignment-01-s.pdf) (and ignore the mistake in the solutions!). The details for creating this style are explained in the accompanying [article](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/mahajan/mahajan.pdf).

That style is created using Metapost in ConTeXt, but it should be relatively easy to create a similar look using TikZ in LaTeX.

Comment: Those crazy margins give me a headache.

Comment: @yoda: I don't understand what you mean by "crazy margins": the hanging indentation of the problems or the randomized frames on the solution.

Comment: I kind of like them. It is a little bit like someone used a pencil to box some text by hand.

Answer (score 5):

I also recommend the `tufte-latex` class with the TikZ package. If your documents include exercises, I suggest you consider the `fortextbook` option of the [`eqexam` package](http://www.math.uakron.edu/~dpstory/eqexam.html).

Answer (score 5):

In order to include high quality vector graphics and even animated pdf files, I recommend [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/). Asymptote is a vector graphics language that uses LaTeX for writing labels, equations, etc. It can generate eps, pdf, jpg and png formats.

Comment: I currently use Tikz for graphics, but always happy to look at other things.

Answer (score 3):

I fully agree with the recommendations for tufte-tex and XeTeX as I use both regularly.  I would also recommend using [sagemath](http://www.sagemath.org/) and the sageTeX package if you have ready access to a non-Microsoft computer.  Though it's not particularly useful for physical handouts, if your students all have computer access, you might consider using the [animate](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/animate) package.  I use all of these packages quite regularly and have been quite pleased with the results.