# Tips to improve look of a thesis?

Tags: thesis

I am writing a thesis at the moment and wondered if anyone has any hints/tips to make it look neat and professional?

I currently have (in my opinion) nice looking tables and page border titles etc.. I was just wondering if there are anything else that is worth adding?

Comment: Breaking the record for getting the fastest `close`-vote? ;-) (No, not by me ;-) ) Your question is opinion based, even under aspects of (good) typography.

Comment: So we don't know what you did for tables, titles, and other things and moreover we don't know what you are missing. *How is my new haircut?* would be an equally difficult thing to answer.

Comment: Without you actually stating *which* stylistic/typographic elements you're concerned with, there's no way for anybody to make useful suggestions. Some of the typographic elements you may care about are font family, font size, interline spacing, linewidths and page margins, use of bold and italics for emphasis, layout of page headers and footers, size of lettering used for sectioning headers, space above and below sectioning headers, layout of title page(s), layout of Table of Contents, etc., etc. At the very least, you need to state your main concerns and what you'd like to do about them.

Comment: These could be relevant to your cause: [How to add some visual style and pizzazz to course notes?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34301) and [Showcase of beautiful title page done in TeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85904) Of course, don't go over board, as too much bling can be hard on the reader :)

Comment: Many (if not most) universities in the US have very strict rules on thesis formatting. Before you go to a lot of effort to make a neat and professional thesis, make sure you're not running afoul of any of your institution's rules. If you're outside the US, my understanding is that their rules are much more relaxed.

Comment: Sorry guys! I had no idea about this rule